# MySQL GROUP BY with Zero values in the count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following query which i need the count of the number of user who has the same golddate as the same day, however since i have to use the GROUP BY it doesnt return the zero values when there is no one on that day, can you please help ?

```
SELECT count( * ) AS total, DATE( `golddate` ) AS gold_date
                FROM `user`
                WHERE YEAR( `golddate` ) >=2014
                GROUP BY DATE( `golddate` )
                ORDER BY DATE( `golddate` ) ASC
```

I want to show something like

```
goldate | total

2012-12-10 | 23
2012-10-12 | 0
```

but issue is it never returns the zero value dates, due to the group by

I tried following but no use,

```
SELECT
  u1.golddate
  -- this will count the number of links to each word
  -- if there are no links the COUNT() call will return 0
  , COUNT(u2.golddate) AS linkCount
FROM user u2
  LEFT JOIN user u1
    ON u1.user_id = u2.user_id
      OR u2.user_id = u1.user_id
GROUP BY u1.golddate
```

Nor even this doesnt work

```
SELECT COALESCE(COUNT(`golddate`), 0) AS total, DATE( `golddate` ) AS gold_count
                FROM `user`
                WHERE YEAR( `golddate` ) >=2014
                GROUP BY DATE( `golddate` )
                ORDER BY DATE( `golddate` ) ASC
```

Comment: There will be no record if you don't have that day in your DB.

Comment: yes , i want to show it as zero that the problem

Comment: You don't understand - there will be nothing to show, not even zero. Since there is no record, there is no converting it to zero.

Comment: Issues of data display are generally best handled at the application level - e.g. a simple php loop. Alternatively you can construct a UNION or utility table to replicate this behaviour. All widely discussed.

Comment: it can be done, if the count value is zero i want to show as zero should be able to do,

Comment: You're not really paying attention, are you?

Comment: @LukasEder - yeah, but that particular question doesn't have the best explanation for _why_ it works, and he needs something a little broader here.  mahen3D - you need something known as a Calendar table - look around to find examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you will need to artificially create the dates for the missing data.

Using [RedFilter's cross join date generation code here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2157776/314291), here's how you can create all dates in a given range, and then LEFT JOIN back to your real data. COUNT(*) needs to be changed to something in the `user` table so as not to count the dummy dates.

```
SELECT count(u.golddate) AS total, a.Date AS golddate
FROM 
(
    select curdate() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY as Date
    from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
) a  

LEFT OUTER JOIN `user` u
  ON DATE(u.golddate) = a.Date

WHERE a.Date between '2013-01-01' and '2013-01-10'

GROUP BY a.Date
ORDER BY a.Date ASC;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ccfa/11)